# SharePoint 2010 Cascading Dropdown error in parent column jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, cascadingdropdown

i know that question is already has been asked but I have read many posts and I didn't found anything for my error(i have try also different versions of javascritpts files(cdn,or downloaded to libary)).Just quick explanation I have three lists cities(title), second list Manicipalities(title,and lookup column CitycodeProperty(Title)) and third list City_Manicipalities(with it has two lookup columns of city and manicipality) where I want for each city to show me only the corresponding municipalities, but it shows me this error for parent column that cannot be found on page. Please any help or advise it will be appreciated. Below it's my code.(the name of "DimoiKinotitesTest" is the municipalities list)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.6.2/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var myJQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

myJQ(document).ready(function(){
    //alert( myJQ.fn.jquery );
    //alert( myJQ().SPServices.Version() );

    // you would put your cascading dropdowns in here, like:
    myJQ().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
    relationshipList: "DimoiKinotitesTest",
    relationshipListParentColumn: "City",    
    relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
    parentColumn: "CityCodeProperty",
    childColumn: "MunicipalityCodeProperty",
    debug: true 

        // options
    });
});

</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np2YR.png)

Comment: What's the two look up columns name in the third list City_Manicipalities? Make sure you enter them correctly.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your reply..the two lookup columns is the "CityCodeProperty"(lookup to Title column of Cities list(first list) which is used as parentColumn in code) and the second one lookup column is the "MunicipalityCodeProperty"(lookup to the Title column of second list "DimoiKinotitesTest") which is the chilcolumn in my code..just for example..in relationshipList which is the "DimoiKinotitesTest" I have the municipality(Title) for one city(lookup column to first list of Title column)..and the name of columns is taken from url in list settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, I found the reason for your issue: You code works fine but you add the JS code to the wrong page.

Please add the code in the NewItem page and editItem page intead of the AllItems page.

Below is my test result.

List DimoiKinotitesTest:
[image]

I reproduced your issue if I add the code in all items page:

[image]

The code works in NewItem page and EditItem page:

[image]

Comment: it works Michael..you was right thank you so much for your help!!!